# IE8 'attr(...)' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, placeholder, attr

I'm trying to get a jquery IE placeholder fix to work.  It works fine in IE9 but in IE8 I keep getting an alert...

> 'attr(...)' is null or not an object

This is the code I am using.  Am I doing something wrong?

```js
<!--[if lte IE 9 ]>
    <script>
        // IE Placeholder Fix
        $(function() {
            if ($('input[placeholder]').attr('placeholder').val() != '') {
                var ph = $('input[placeholder]').attr('placeholder');
                $('input[placeholder]').blur();
                if ($('input[placeholder]').attr('value').val() == 0) {
                    $('input[placeholder]').attr('value', ph);
                    $('input[placeholder]').css('color','#999999');
                };
                $('input[placeholder]').click(
                    function() {
                        $(this).css('color','#000000');
                        if ($(this).attr('value') == ph) {
                            $(this).attr('value','');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

**UPDATE:**

Using the comments below I came up with...

```js
<!--[if lte IE 9 ]>
    <script>
        // IE Placeholder Fix
        $(function() {
            if ($('input[placeholder]').length != 0) {
                var ph = $('input[placeholder]').attr('placeholder');
                $('input[placeholder]').blur();
                if ($('input[placeholder]').attr('value') == '') {
                    $('input[placeholder]').attr('value', ph);
                    $('input[placeholder]').css('color','#999999');
                };
                $('input[placeholder]').click(
                    function() {
                        $(this).css('color','#000000');
                        if ($(this).attr('value') == ph) {
                            $(this).attr('value','');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Perhaps `$('input[placeholder]').attr('placeholder')` or `$('input[placeholder]').attr('value')` returns null?

Comment: My first guess: is this: `$('input[placeholder]').attr('value').val()` correct? Can you actually call val() on what attr() returns? I think not...

Comment: @Asad - Thanks that did the trick.  I also was wrongly using .val() on further in.  Post an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a method or property on a null object will result in errors of the sort you are experiencing. If you are not sure if an object is defined, test this before referring to any children.